# what device might control an JAE 50 pin hard drive drive coil wipe function?

Tags: hard-drive, devices

I have a CF-28 Panasonic toughbook. it has a coil around the hard drive that can allegedly wipe the (mechanical) disk in the event I so choose.

It is attached on pins 1,2 of the JAE50 pin header, The hard drive is a mini IDE, but the JAE50 pin connector has some pins that arnt used for data. pins 1,2 are labled as eject, or Audio depending on the datasheet you might look at. I tried the eject command, but it was not successful. I'm not sure what device file would address the control of the coil. Are there any utilities to utilize such devices? Or, what file(s) in /dev might give me control of the disk wipe coil? or what functions (Kernel) would give me control of pins 1,2 of a JAE50 pin connector? The JAE50 pin connector is pretty common for cd drives.

Comment: I have never heard of something like this. It is possible that there is not a feature for this in most if not all distributions. Aside from hitting the drive with a super strong electromagnetic field, I'm not sure how that would wipe the drive. If it is an electromagnet strong enough to overwrite the data on the disk, then I wonder how it doesn't destroy it and/or the sectors and everything.

Comment: I've build such devices in the past. "Super strong" isnt necessary, simply putting a magnet on a disk, and letting it run for a while has proven to be quite effective. This is the first computer where I have seen such a device integrated into it. For the devices I have build, yes, the drives often acquire significant damage to the read write heads, platters, and drive motor. (depending on duration of operation). For my own use, and yes, I have multiple mini ide mechanical hard drives to test this on.

Comment: Not described in your manual https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf4/82/8182/818119-panasonic/cf28.pdf?e451d30d3ac8e50e0507e4c4b6518b95 Perhaps you could provide a web link to where you read of this HDD erasing coil?